# SQL Current date (AS400)

Tags: sql, date, ibm-midrange

I am trying to select the records from an AS400 database that have a current date (in format MMDDYY).

This is what I am planning to do:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE $DATE='030411'
```

I tried combinations of this but with no luck:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE $DATE='SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 1), '/', '')'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The question needs clarification. Every row in every table effectively has a "current date". The current date is a special register that's always available; it's not a value that's physically retrieved from a column. Definition of "current date" is needed. And DATE columns don't have a format. A "MMDDYY" format would come from settings on the connection or the presentation client. Change settings to get a different format. We need to know connection details. But if the column is really a CHAR, VARCHAR, DECIMAL or other data type and not a DATE, we need to know that, too.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE $DATE=
   substring(cast(current date as char(10)),6,2) || 
   substring(cast(current date as char(10)),9,2) || 
   substring(cast(current date as char(10)),3,2)
```

You can see what value this expression brings back like this:

```
select substring(cast(current date as char(10)),6,2) || 
   substring(cast(current date as char(10)),9,2) || 
   substring(cast(current date as char(10)),3,2)    
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

You have to use `sysibm.sysdummy1` since SQL on an AS/400 (iSeries, System i, etc.) doesn't let you `SELECT` values out of thin air.

Also note that `current date` might bring the date back in a different format, depending on the SQL date format.  This code is expecting it to be in *ISO format (`YYYY-MM-DD`).

Here are some SQL statements that I used to validate this routine.

```
create table dmclib.test2 ( $DATE decimal(6,0) ) ;

insert into dmclib.test2 values   
  (010111), (010211), (031011) ;

SELECT * FROM dmclib.test2                         
where $DATE =                                      
   substring(cast(current date as char(10)),6,2) ||
   substring(cast(current date as char(10)),9,2) ||
   substring(cast(current date as char(10)),3,2) ;
```

Here's what I got back:

```
....+...                        
  $DATE                         
 31,011                         
********  End of data  ********
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work either. I know the format in this date field is MMDDYY

Comment: Are you getting an error message or just not getting any rows back?  What comes back if you write `select current date from sysibm.sysdummy1`?

Comment: BTW, if `select current date from sysibm.sysdummy1` doesn't work, try it as `select current date from sysibm/sysdummy1` (in case your SQL session is using *SYS naming convention).

Answer (score 2):

```
insert( replace( char( current_date, usa ) , '/', '' ) , 5, 2, '')
```

The above generates the character string representation of the *USA format [i.e. `MM/DD/YYYY`] for the Current Date using the `CHAR` cast scalar function, then replaces the '/' character in the string `MM/DD/YYYY` with the null string to become `MMDDYYYY` using the `REPLACE` scalar function, and then inserts the null string starting as position five [i.e. the first digit of `YYYY` in `MMDDYYYY`] while removing two bytes of that string [i.e. the "insert" is actually replacing the fifth and sixth bytes, or per the arguments on the insert scalar from the fifth (5) for two (2) bytes, with the null string] using the `INSERT` scalar function, thus producing the desired result of the string `MMDDYY` [where the last two bytes `YY` are the 10**1 and 10**0 portions of the number denoted as `YYYY` in `MM/DD/YYYY`].

Regards, Chuck

Answer (score 0):

**030411** =

> select
>   substring(Replace(Replace(convert(varchar(10),GETDATE(),
>   101), '/', ''), '/', ''),1,4)+
>   substring(convert(varchar(4),year(GETDATE()),101),3,2)

Comment: Thats wired , just copy and run the select query into SQL server. It should return the MMDDYY formated value.

Comment: This question is for AS/400, not SQL Server

Comment: When I execute this on AS400 it says "GETDATE in *LIBL type *N not found."

Answer (score -1):

Try the below steps..

1. STRSQL
2. TYPE YOUR QUERY
3. PRESS F4
4. PUT YOUR CURSOR IN FRONT OF "WHERE"
5. PRESS F4
6. PUT 1 IN FRONT OF YOUR APPROPRIATE DATE COLUMN NAME
7. HIT ENTER
8. IF YOUR COLUMN IS NUMERIC GIVE VALUE WITHOUT QUOTES E.G 1234 AND NOT '1234'
9. HIT ENTER
10. YOU SHOULD GET YOUR RESULT